# How to add control to existing view?

Tags: android

I'm working on an app which allows users to take a snapshot of their active SMS messages.

Is it possible to add a button on the existing android SMS message view without changing the default SMS sending application?

I just want to add some of a widget to the default sms app which the user already has installed... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**No this is definitelly not possible**..You can intercept for incoming messages with proper permissions though..Also you can write an app which will read SMS messages stored on the device..

**But you really cant write an app modifying existing SMS app..**

It's actually [opensource](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms), so you can easily get its sources and you can then try to make some changes and possibly to release it as a separate application on the Google Play.

Comment: How about having my app run in the background, listening to screen openings and if the current screen is SMS messanger, add an overlay which is not a part of the app physicaly but it just looks like it is.. would such a thing be possible?

Comment: yes that would be possible..but the user will be only able to interact with either your overlay, or the app underneath..not both at the same time..

Comment: Well, if that's just a button, would the user be able to either click that button OR just use the app underneath? or would he actualy need to switch applications in the android "task manager"? by the way, do you have an idea where i can start looking to do create such a thing?